# Name That Name?... 5

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Ever since my origin, I've been crowned by God

A male Israeli diplomat contradicts my feminine bond

Spelled 3 different ways, my longest way is now bad

Because of a fraud to a profession that marvelous Marple had

Name this name

P.S. I will give props if you get this name, it is difficult

Hint #1

> This name is of a Yiddish origin

Comment: By the way, sorry I've been gone for 2 months, I hope to get back into posting these again

Comment: Parcival, if you read ready player one has three spellings

Comment: No, it isn't Parcival either

Comment: The reason this name is hard is because it is really rare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Name is

> Katriel

Ever since my origin, I've been crowned by God

> Of Hebrew origin, the name means "crowned by God"

A male Israeli diplomat contradicts my feminine bond

> The name can be feminine, but also masculine, as evidenced by Israeli diplomat [Katriel Katz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katriel_Katz)

Spelled 3 different ways, my longest way is now bad
Because of a fraud to a profession that marvelous Marple had

> Variants include Katriela and Katrielle. I think this clue refers to [Katrielle Layton](http://layton.wikia.com/wiki/Katrielle_Layton) from the Professor Layton games, since Katrielle is the daughter of a detective (The same profession as Agatha Christie's Miss Marple character)

Comment: Amazing! You nailed it, though the 4th line refers to her fraudulent ways, not the dad.

Comment: I actually wonder, did you know most of this without research?!

Comment: I wish I could claim that I did! Actually, I used [behindthename](https://www.behindthename.com/). First I searched for Hebrew names meaning "Crowned by God", "crown", or "God". When that didn't work I went through all the Hebrew names in turn. So, more perspiration then inspiration! :P

Comment: Did you get the other lines okay though

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer

> John

Spelled 3 different ways, my longest way is now bad

> Jon, John and Jonathan (Jonathan Banks - Breaking bad, Better Call Saul - crooked cop - related Marple from Agatha Christie)

Comment: No, this name is definitely one many will have to research, each day that goes without a correct answer, I'll post a hint on what to look for